# How can Get the current Route and adjust one value in asp.net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a request and it has a route but there are loads of them as set up in the global.asax...one typical route is...

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "NewStore",
                "{culture}/{client}/{brand}/NewStore/{action}",
                new
                {
                    culture = UrlParameter.Optional,
                    client = UrlParameter.Optional,
                    brand = UrlParameter.Optional,
                    controller = "NewStore",
                    action = "Index"
                }
                );
```

I need to create a ddl that switches the culture on the page. So actually all I want to do is recreate the route url but change one argument. So I want to do something lhe this...

```
    Route currentRoute = httpContext.GetCurrentRoute();
    Route englishCultureRoute = currentRoute;
    Route spanishRoute = currentRoute;
    englishCultureRoute.RouteData.Values["culture"] = "en-en"
    spanishRoute RouteData.Values["culture"] = "es-es"

@Html.SelectListForRoutes(englishCultureRoute,spanishRoute);
```

So the above is pseudocode, I want to do the first bit in a controller but how do I do this in c#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can access the route data from the controller from

```
RouteData
```

if you want to assign new values you can do something like this

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    RouteData.Values["id"] = 555;
    return View();
}
```

and in the view you can access the route data values from

```
@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Id"]
```

but if your taking about globalizing your app there are better solutions , you can check [this](http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx)